# Scroll bar diappears when drawer is open in MUI v5 React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, scrollbar

I am making a responsive drawer in React with mui v5. I have set a min-width of 600px when the drawer becomes full width. When the screen gets bigger than 600px then the width of the drawer changes to 240px.

When the screen is bigger than 600px there is a problem that when the drawer is open the scroll bar of the page disappears and can not scroll the page and when It is closed the scroll bar appears and we can scroll the page.

I want that the scroll bar appears when the drawer is opened.

Everything is fine when the width is 600px or less than it.

Here is a code sandbox : [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hawking-rd7tvs?file=/src/App.js:742-13935)

```
const drawerWidth = 240;
const transitionDuration = 1000; //can also use theme.transitions.duration

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => {
  return {
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: (theme) => theme.spacing(2)
    },
    hide: {
      display: "none"
    },
    appBar: {
      zIndex: (theme) => `${theme.zIndex.drawer + 1} !important`
    },
    drawer: {
      width: (theme) => theme.drawerWidth,
      "& .MuiBackdrop-root": {
        display: "none"
      }
    },
    drawerPaper: {
      width: (theme) => theme.drawerWidth,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2)"
    },
    content: {
      padding: (theme) => theme.spacing(3),
      transition: (theme) =>
        theme.transitions.create("margin", {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
          duration: transitionDuration
        }),
      minWidth: (theme) => theme.drawerWidth,
      marginLeft: (theme) => 0
    },
    contentShift: {
      transition: (theme) =>
        theme.transitions.create("margin", {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
          duration: transitionDuration
        }),
      minWidth: (theme) => theme.drawerWidth,
      marginLeft: (theme) => theme.drawerWidth
    }
  };
});

export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const greaterThan375 = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");
  theme.drawerWidth = greaterThan375 ? drawerWidth : "100%";
  const classes = useStyles(theme);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(greaterThan375);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(greaterThan375);
  }, [greaterThan375]);

  const handleMenuClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/*fixed is default */}
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton //hide on desktop
            color="inherit"
            onClick={handleMenuClick}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, greaterThan375 && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Responsive Drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        //add full width for responsive
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="temporary"
        //elevation={3} only works with variant="temporary"
        open={open}
        transitionDuration={{
          enter: transitionDuration,
          exit: transitionDuration
        }}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper
        }}
        PaperProps={{ elevation: 9 }}
      >
        <Toolbar />
        <div>
          <List>
            {["Home", "Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3"].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <AppsIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </div>
      </Drawer>
      <main className={clsx(classes.content, { [classes.contentShift]: open })}>
        <Toolbar />
        <Typography>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et
          commodo nulla, in elementum lacus. Cras mollis accumsan quam, sit amet
          finibus orci posuere et. Suspendisse euismod lorem congue dapibus
          porta. Mauris lacinia eu velit suscipit maximus. Aliquam fermentum
          commodo libero, id facilisis sapien. Maecenas gravida vel odio et
          vestibulum. Aenean dignissim dolor nec purus volutpat efficitur. Proin
          egestas posuere lobortis. Vestibulum dui orci, tincidunt eu neque vel,
          ullamcorper aliquet magna. Maecenas sit amet rhoncus purus, vel
          molestie ligula. Sed eleifend a tortor eget pretium. Suspendisse orci
          enim, lobortis sit amet posuere vel, dapibus vitae mauris. Fusce
          venenatis mauris quam, volutpat vehicula leo elementum vitae. Nam
          molestie, metus sit amet lobortis lobortis, quam leo vulputate nisi,
          non mattis nisi justo sed sapien. Nam eleifend felis non ante
          imperdiet, sed porttitor nunc facilisis. Cras a magna sem. Nunc cursus
          velit ut orci varius, ut facilisis arcu venenatis. Curabitur eget
          risus mi. Nullam dapibus urna id mauris viverra, et tempus lectus
          mollis. Quisque urna nibh, rhoncus id posuere scelerisque, imperdiet
          vel felis. Proin nec imperdiet magna, id interdum tortor. Donec
        </Typography>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing the drawers variant from temporary to persistent.

```
<Drawer
      //add full width for responsive
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="persistent"
        //elevation={3} only works with variant="temporary"
        open={open}
        transitionDuration={{
          enter: transitionDuration,
          exit: transitionDuration
        }}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper
        }}
        // PaperProps={{ elevation: 9 }}
      >
        <Toolbar/>
        <div>
          <List>
            {["Home", "Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3"].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <AppsIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </div>
      </Drawer>
```

Comment: But then the drawer is rendered even when not opened

Answer (score 2):

Drawer is using Modal behind the scene, and the on the Drawer there is a `ModalProps` property with which you can add props to the Modal. And on the Modal there is a `disableScrollLock` flag, and that is what you need in this case.

```
      <Drawer
        // ...
        ModalProps={{ disableScrollLock: true }}
      >
        // ...
      </Drawer>
```